# Async in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, asynchronous

Is it possible to do async stuff in WinForms like we can in Metro apps on Windows 8?

For example:

```
protected async void Something()
{
    await FileIO.Something();
}
```

would be really cool to have in WinForms.

Comment: It was *built* to do this.  This is one of the primary reasons this feature was implemented in the first place.

Comment: @Servy: He apparently thinks it was built only for WinRT.

Comment: @Servy, I thought you could do it, but I have never, ever seen any code samples where people have used async/await in their WinForms code. Granted, it is pretty new, but still; I would've thought there'd be a huge explosion of new code online with async/await for WinForms. So that's what made me question whether or not it really was possible/good practice.

Comment: @SLaks Yes, that's mostly correct. I originally thought it was a general C# feature, but after only ever seeing it used in Metro apps, I began to question that.

Comment: Examples of this are everywhere. Please search either this site or _the whole of the internet_ before posting.

Answer (score 4):

Yes.

Async is a C# 5.0 language feature and will work anywhere, as long as you have the supporting BCL types (.Net 4.5, or Microsoft.Bcl.Async from NuGet).

However, you should never write `async void`s anywhere, except for event handlers.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can obtain an asynchronous UI using async-await in winform.
You have to start an asynchronous task in event handler with Tast.Run method without awaiting it.
To access any control property or method, you have to do it into main thread using Control.Invoke method.

At last, with this approach the ui remain ever active and can handle other event while previus code is running. then you have to write code to disable enable button or other event handling while code is running